# Why is a DMSO-only Control Important?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, cell-culture

[image]Why is it necessary to have a DMSO alone control when DMSO has been used as the solvent (vehicle) in the treated conditions?

And, in this case, why is the viability of the untreated condition lower than the vehicle (DMSO alone)?

Comment: It could simply be that the reagents or drugs involved dissolve well in DMSO and poorly in other solvents. Vehicles are a way of saying this is the drug/reagent + solvent. As always, when DMSO is the solvent, include DMSO-alone controls so you know the effect you're seeing isn't a result of the DMSO.

Comment: @CMyosychuk So we use it in order to know whether the drug or reagent itself that has effect on cell viability, right? And based on the above graph, why do the graph of Vehicle is higher than None?

Comment: @Sokviseth Its not possible to give a clear 'why' answer to that question. The most probably reason is just biological variance, from your two different samples. Also note that the SD (which doesnt make a lot of sense for 2 samples anyway) for the vehicle control is very large.

Comment: As @Nicolai said, this is most likely simply variance, with more independent samples, the difference will probably be smaller. Additionally, given these error bars, I would see the untreated and the DMSO samples as the same. The treated samples are pretty much different from them.

Comment: @Sokviseth What's your measure here (the axis values)? If it's indeed a measure of viability, basically you're saying your drugs are dissolved in DMSO, and you want to see the effect of the drugs vs. no drugs. *But*, the DMSO can affect viability, too, so you have to do a DMSO alone condition. Your **goal**, however, is you actually *want* to say that the DMSO had no effect so you can see the pure effect of your drugs. The p-value between your none and vehicle is like 0.5, which means they aren't different, which is good because your drug readouts will have no/little background.

Comment: In my opinion, you want to get a third replicate though to give yourself the best statistical power, and make those error bars a little tighter.

Comment: I edited the question so it may be reopened

Comment: @CMosychuk Why do you think this question should be reopened? This is a pretty simple homework-style question.

Comment: @CMosychuk Thanks for your explanation :-)  I learned a lot from you!

Comment: @BryanKrause Every question should be welcomed. It is might be simple for you, but it is not for someone else. I just need to get some ideas from this forum. :-) Science is about discussion.

Comment: @Sokviseth The reason for the prohibition on homework questions is that homework is designed to direct your learning, and asking on SE bypasses the normal ways to obtain that information. A lot of what you are supposed to be learning about is actually how to obtain the information, not just obtaining the information itself.

Comment: @BryanKrause The way I worded it in my edits probably made it more homework than it is. To the layman, seeing a DMSO control in a scientific figure might not immediately make sense. *I* know that it's for when DMSO is involved in the treatments, but I don't think it jumps out at people who aren't used to drug preparations. This is a good question for basic experimental design: looking for, and controlling for confounding variables.